# Should I include the current language code in <link rel="alternate" hreflang="" />?

Tags: seo, multilingual, rel-alternate

I have a multilingual site and I have the following `<link rel="alternate" >` in the head section.

```
<link href="http://www.example.com/en" rel="canonical" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://www.example.com/en" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="ja" href="http://www.example.com/ja" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="zh-CN" href="http://www.example.com/zh-CN" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="ko" href="http://www.example.com/ko" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://www.example.com" hreflang="x-default" />
```

I have read several articles including Google guidelines, but I'm still confusing to include the current language code for `rel="alternate"`.

In the example above, the current languague is `en`. Should I include `<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://www.example.com/en" />`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes! In [a recent blog post](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2014/05/creating-right-homepage-for-your.html) we mentioned:

> Your [rel-alternate-hreflang] annotations should be self-referential. Page A should use rel-alternate-hreflang annotation linking to itself.

Comment: Is there any reason for that? `rel=alternate` is made for **alternatives**, and neither the blog post nor the [webmaster article](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en) explains that.

Comment: The main reasons are that it makes it easier to reuse the same block of annotations on all pages of the set, as well as making sure that canonicalization issues don't cause unnecessary problems. For example, if /en.htm?sessionid=123 doesn't mention that /en.htm is the English version, we may assume that the "sessionid=123" part is important (but not confirmed by the other pages).

Comment: Hmm, so Google uses `rel-canonical` and `rel=alternate` for the **same purpose**? Sounds like a serious bug to me. I hesitate to implement a workaround for this duplicated functionality in our plugin with more than 50k users.